# How to make grouping of inner circle and Orange circle dynamic?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, reactjs

I need to make Below image dynamically but I am to create circle and inner circle dynamically but I need to make group of inner circles dynamically.

[This is we want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2j53.jpg)

the problem is I am to create Circle and inner circle but not Able to make
1.Grouping of inner circle
2.Not abe to show orange outside services dynamically

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Mango Dynamic Team Generator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="team.css">
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="canvas" class="center"></div>
    <script src="team.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

team.js

```
/*
// Get the JSON data for the team
fetch('team.json').then(function (response) {
  return  response.json();
}).then(function (obj) {
  console.log(obj);
}).catch(function (error) {
  console.error('Something went wrong with retrieving the data!');
  console.error(error);
});
*/

const json = `{
  "team": "The Avengers Team",
  "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vel auctor leo. Proin in elit at lectus viverra pharetra. Cras rutrum elit nibh, dapibus mollis nulla facilisis vel.",
  "date": "2014-06-25T00:00:00.000Z",
  "version": 1.2,
  "members": [
    {
      "name" : "Captain America",
      "role" : "Product Execution",
      "type" : "lead",
      "percent" : "70%",
      "subteam" : "",
      "subteam_color" : ""

    },
    {
      "name" : "Nick Fury",
      "role" : "Mentor",
      "type" : "mentor",
      "percent" : "",
      "subteam" : "",
      "subteam_color" : ""
    },
    {
      "name" : "Bruce Banner",
      "role" : "Media",
      "type" : "normal",
      "percent" : "",
      "subteam" : "",
      "subteam_color" : ""
    },
    {
      "name" : "Stan Lee",
      "role" : "Content",
      "type" : "normal",
      "percent" : "70%",
      "subteam" : "",
      "subteam_color" : ""
    },
    {
      "name" : "Nick Fury",
      "role" : "Mentor",
      "type" : "mentor",
      "percent" : "",
      "subteam" : "",
      "subteam_color" : ""
    },
    {
      "name" : "Bruce Banner",
      "role" : "Media",
      "type" : "normal",
      "percent" : "",
      "subteam" : "",
      "subteam_color" : ""
    },
    {
      "name" : "Stan Lee",
      "role" : "Content",
      "type" : "normal",
      "percent" : "70%",
      "subteam" : "",
      "subteam_color" : ""
    },
    {
      "name" : "New Hire",
      "role" : "Product Execution",
      "type" : "placeholder_subteamlead",
      "percent" : "90%",
      "subteam" : "software",
      "subteam_color" : ""
    },
    {
      "name" : "Pepper Potts",
      "role" : "Software Development",
      "type" : "normal",
      "percent" : "80%",
      "subteam" : "software",
      "subteam_color" : ""
    },
    {
      "name" : "Iron Man",
      "role" : "Software Development",
      "type" : "normal",
      "percent" : "80%",
      "subteam" : "software",
      "subteam_color" : ""
    }
  ]
}`;

const obj = JSON.parse(json);
console.log(obj.members);

// Set the total number of team members
var totalTeamMembers = obj.members.length;

// Calculate the radius of the team circles
if (totalTeamMembers < 11) {
  var radius = 220;
} else {
  var radius = 20 * totalTeamMembers;
}

// Calculate the divisions
var divisions = 360 / totalTeamMembers;

// Offset for the center of the team circles
var offsetToTeamMemberCenter = 35;

// Get the canvas div by its ID
var canvasDiv = document.getElementById('canvas');

// Create a new div for the team container circle...
var teamDiv = document.createElement('div');

// ...and set the ID to "team"
teamDiv.setAttribute("id", "team");

if (totalTeamMembers < 11) {
  var teamDivDiameter = 580;
} else {
  var teamDivDiameter = (radius * 2) + 130;
}

// ...and set the width and height values
teamDiv.style.width = teamDivDiameter + "px";
teamDiv.style.height = teamDivDiameter + "px";

// Append the team div to the canvas div
canvasDiv.appendChild(teamDiv);

// Reference the team div for some values
var teamDiv = document.getElementById('team');

var offsetToTeamCenter = parseInt(teamDiv.offsetWidth / 2); //assumes team is square
var offsetToTeamCenter = teamDiv.offsetWidth / 2; //assumes team is square
var offsetToTeamCenterHeight = teamDiv.offsetHeight / 2;
console.log("offsetToTeamCenter = " + offsetToTeamCenter);
var totalOffset = offsetToTeamCenter - offsetToTeamMemberCenter;
console.log("totalOffset = " + totalOffset);

var teamDescriptionDiv = document.createElement('div');
var teamDescriptionSpan = document.createElement('span');
var teamDescriptionHeadline = document.createElement('h2');
var teamDescriptionMissionLabel = document.createElement('h3');
var teamDescriptionBody = document.createElement('p');
teamDescriptionDiv.setAttribute("id", "teamDescription");
teamDescriptionSpan.setAttribute("id", "description");
teamDescriptionDiv.setAttribute("class", "center");
teamDescriptionSpan.setAttribute("class", "center");
teamDescriptionHeadline.innerHTML = obj.team;
teamDescriptionMissionLabel.innerHTML = 'Team Mission:';
teamDescriptionBody.innerHTML = obj.description;
canvasDiv.appendChild(teamDescriptionDiv);
teamDescriptionDiv.appendChild(teamDescriptionSpan);
teamDescriptionSpan.appendChild(teamDescriptionHeadline);
teamDescriptionSpan.appendChild(teamDescriptionMissionLabel);
teamDescriptionSpan.appendChild(teamDescriptionBody);

// Create a container div for arcs
var arcDiv = document.createElement('div');
arcDiv.setAttribute("class", "arc center");
teamDiv.appendChild(arcDiv);

// Create arcs for subteams
function createArc(i) {

  var arcSVG = document.createElement('svg');
  arcSVG.setAttribute("width", "500px");
  arcSVG.setAttribute("height", "500px");
  arcDiv.appendChild(arcSVG);

  var tau = 2 * Math.PI; // http://tauday.com/tau-manifesto

  // An arc function with all values bound except the endAngle. Something , to compute an
  // SVG path string for a given angle, we pass an object with an endAngle
  // property to the `arc` function, and it will return the corresponding string.
  var arc = d3.arc()
      .innerRadius(80)
      .outerRadius(140)
      .startAngle(0)
      .cornerRadius(30);

  // Get the SVG container, and apply a transform such that the origin is the
  // center of the canvas. This way, we don’t need to position arcs individually.
  var svg = d3.select("svg"),
      width = +svg.attr("width"),
      height = +svg.attr("height"),
      g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

  // Add the background arc, from 0 to 100% (tau).
  /* var background = g.append("path")
      .datum({endAngle: tau})
      .style("fill", "#ddd")
      .attr("d", arc); */

  // Add the foreground arc in orange, currently showing 12.7%.
  var foreground = g.append("path")
      .datum({endAngle: 0.627 * tau})
      .style("fill", "#e90b3a")
      .attr("d", arc);
}

createArc(1);

/* Create a circle for each role on the team and label it with the role and person's name */
for (var i = 0; i < totalTeamMembers; ++i) {
  var teamMemberType = obj.members[i].type;
  console.log("i = "  + i.toString());
  var teamMemberDiv = document.createElement('div'); 
  // teamMemberDiv.style.position = 'absolute';
  var x = -Math.sin((divisions * i) * (Math.PI / 180)) * radius; //Normally the x-axis is cos but I want the first circle to be at 12:00.
  console.log("x = " + Math.round(x).toString());
  var y = -Math.cos((divisions * i) * (Math.PI / 180)) * radius;
  console.log("y = " + Math.round(y).toString());


  switch(teamMemberType) {
    case "normal":
      teamMemberDiv.className = 'roleCircle teamMember';
      teamMemberDiv.style.top = (y + totalOffset).toString() + "px";
      teamMemberDiv.style.left = (x + totalOffset).toString() + "px";
      break;
    case "lead":
      teamMemberDiv.className = 'roleCircle teamMemberLead';
      teamMemberDiv.style.top = (y + totalOffset - 2).toString() + "px";
      teamMemberDiv.style.left = (x + totalOffset - 2).toString() + "px";
      break;
    case "subteamlead":
      teamMemberDiv.className = 'roleCircle teamMemberSubteamLead';
      teamMemberDiv.style.top = (y + totalOffset - 2).toString() + "px";
      teamMemberDiv.style.left = (x + totalOffset - 2).toString() + "px";
      break;
    case "mentor":
      teamMemberDiv.className = 'roleCircle teamMemberMentor';
      teamMemberDiv.style.top = (y + totalOffset).toString() + "px";
      teamMemberDiv.style.left = (x + totalOffset).toString() + "px";
      break;
    case "placeholder_normal":
      teamMemberDiv.className = 'roleCircle teamMemberPlaceholderNormal';
      teamMemberDiv.style.top = (y + totalOffset - 2).toString() + "px";
      teamMemberDiv.style.left = (x + totalOffset - 2).toString() + "px";
      break;
    case "placeholder_lead":
      teamMemberDiv.className = 'roleCircle teamMemberPlaceholderLead';
      teamMemberDiv.style.top = (y + totalOffset - 2).toString() + "px";
      teamMemberDiv.style.left = (x + totalOffset - 2).toString() + "px";
      break;
    case "placeholder_subteamlead":
      teamMemberDiv.className = 'roleCircle teamMemberPlaceholderSubteamLead';
      teamMemberDiv.style.top = (y + totalOffset - 2).toString() + "px";
      teamMemberDiv.style.left = (x + totalOffset - 2).toString() + "px";
      break;
    default:
      teamMemberDiv.className = 'roleCircle teamMember';
      teamMemberDiv.style.top = (y + totalOffset).toString() + "px";
      teamMemberDiv.style.left = (x + totalOffset).toString() + "px";
  }


  /* Find the center of the role cirlce */
  /* var horizontalCenter = teamMemberDiv.offsetWidth / 2;
  var verticalCenter = teamMemberDiv.offsetHeight / 2;
  console.log("x of circle = " + horizontalCenter.toString());
  console.log("y of circle = " + verticalCenter.toString()); */

  /* Set the Functional Role within the Team Member Circle */
  var roleName = document.createElement('div');
  var roleNameText = document.createElement('div');
  roleName.className = 'roleName';
  roleNameText.className = 'roleNameText center';
  // Set font-size based on character length
  var roleNameTextSize = 12;
  if (obj.members[i].role.length > 7) {
    roleNameTextSize = 8;
  }
  roleNameText.setAttribute("style", "font-size: " + roleNameTextSize + "px;");
  roleNameText.innerHTML = obj.members[i].role;
  // roleNameText.textContent = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";
  roleNameVerticalCenter = 22;
  roleNameHorizontalCenter = 5;
  console.log("role x = " + roleNameHorizontalCenter.toString());
  console.log("role y = " + roleNameVerticalCenter.toString());
  roleName.style.top = (y + roleNameVerticalCenter + totalOffset).toString() + "px";
  roleName.style.left = (x + roleNameHorizontalCenter + totalOffset).toString() + "px";

  /* Set the Team Member's Name at the bottome of the Team Member Circle */ 
  var personName = document.createElement('div');
  personName.className = 'personName';
  if (obj.members[i].percent != "") {
    personName.innerHTML = obj.members[i].name  + ' (' + obj.members[i].percent + ')';
  } else {
    personName.innerHTML = obj.members[i].name;
  }
  personNameVerticalCenter = 80;
  personNameHorizontalCenter = 29;
  console.log("person x = " + personNameHorizontalCenter.toString());
  console.log("person y = " + personNameVerticalCenter.toString());
  personName.style.top = (y + personNameVerticalCenter + totalOffset - 5).toString() + "px";
  personName.style.left = (x + personNameHorizontalCenter + totalOffset - 34).toString() + "px";

  /* Find the center of the teamMember circle */
  //var teamMemberCenter = teamMemberDiv.scrollHeight;
  //console.log("width = " + teamMemberCenter.toString());

  /* Add the Div Tags to the HTML Document */
  teamDiv.appendChild(teamMemberDiv);
  teamDiv.appendChild(roleName);
  roleName.appendChild(roleNameText);
  teamDiv.appendChild(personName);
}
```

team.css

```
h2 {
    margin: 20px;
}

h3 {
    margin: 0;
}

p {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
}

#canvas {

  }

#team {
    background-color: #4587A4;
    border-radius: 100%;
  }

#teamDescription {
    font-family: Arial;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 100%;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
  }

#description {
    font-family: Arial;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    width: 300px;
  }

.roleCircle {
    font-family: Arial;
    position: absolute;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    border-radius: 100px;
}

.teamMember {
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  }

.teamMemberLead {
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    border: 2px solid #00E0FF;
  }

.teamMemberSubteamLead {
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    border: 2px solid #FC72FF;
  }

.teamMemberLead {
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    border: 2px solid #00E0FF;
  }

.teamMemberPlaceholderNormal {
    border: 2px dashed #fff;
  }

.teamMemberPlaceholderLead {
    border: 2px dashed #00E0FF;
  }

.teamMemberPlaceholderSubteamLead {
    border: 2px dashed #FC72FF;
  }

.teamMemberMentor {
    opacity: 0.25;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  }

.roleName {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 60px;
    height: 30px;
    max-width: 60px;
    max-height: 30px;
    /* border: 1px dashed white; */
  }

.roleNameText {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    /* font-size: 9px; This will be done dynamically */
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
  }

.personName {
    font-family: Arial;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 80px;
    height: 20px;
    max-width: 80px;
    max-height: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 10px;
    /* border: 1px dashed white; */
  }

.center {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: Based on the UI the first thing is the JSON needs to be sorted according to how you want them to be grouped. Sent you a proposal over UW.

Comment: yes that we will do it but how to design that that is main concern

Comment: You have to wrap the common circles once sorted.

Comment: I would advice you to remove the canvas and add code using HTML.

Comment: How from the JSON can I work out the groupings?